# Add an image (and on click redirect to URL) in one of the columns in kendo grid

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I have kendo grid as such

```
<kendo-grid
  [data]="gridData"
  [selectable]="false"
  [kendoGridSelectBy]="'Id'"
  [selectedKeys]="selectedIds"
  [pageable]="{ pageSizes: gridPageSizes }"
  [pageSize]="state.take"
  [skip]="state.skip"
  [scrollable]="'none'"
  [groupable]="false"
  [group]="state.group"
  (dataStateChange)="dataStateChange($event)"
  [filterable]="false"
  [filter]="state?.filter"
  [sortable]="true"
  [sort]="state?.sort"
  [rowClass]="rowCallBack"
>
<kendo-grid-column
    field="invoiceNumber"
    title="Invoice Number"
  >
  </kendo-grid-column>
 <kendo-grid-column
    title="PO"
  >
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
      {{dataItem.PO}}
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>

 <kendo-grid-column
    field="StatusChangedDate"
    title="StatusChangedDate"
    filter="date"
    format="{0:d}"
  >
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <time>{{ dataItem.StatusChangedDate | l10nDate: language:'short' }}</time>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

Please let me know how can I add a column  which has an image based on the 'data' (URL data) .And on click of an image it redirects to the URL.

I tried something like this

```
<kendo-grid-column
  title="Ticket"
>
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
    <div *ngIf="dataItem.Ticket != null">
      <a class="title-logo" href="dataItem.Ticket"><img src="/images/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

Image is displayed , which is clickabale, But when clicked on the image doesnt go to the desired link that is loaded as part of dataItem.Ticket on href

Thanks

Comment: Make an image as explained [here](https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) and wrap it in an `<a href="....` element.

Comment: Hi Galois, Can you please eloborate and give me some sample on stackblitz as an example where there is an image in the column and when clicked on an image it redirects to a URL on browser

Comment: <kendo-grid-column
  title="Ticket"
>
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem="dataItem">
    <div *ngIf="dataItem.Ticket != null">
      <a class="title-logo" href="dataItem.Ticket"><img src="/images/logo.png" /></a>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>                                                                                  
Image is displayed , which is clickabale, But when clicked on the image doesnt go to the desired link that is loaded as part of dataItem.Ticket on href

Comment: I'm not fluent in angular. I think it should be something like `<a href="{{dataItem.Ticket}}"` (something dynamic anyway) , but I'm not sure what your data looks like.